# MVVM ListBox ItemSource Get Collection Name

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I am implementing dynamic drag and drop over multiple listboxes, where I need to figure out collection name at runtime.

What I mean -> when executing **OnDrop** event I have to either add item to an already existing collection (collection can have more than one member), or replace already existing item (in a collection that can only have one member). I want to do something like following:

```
var collection = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox).ItemsSource as IList;
if (collection.GetName() == "col_AllData")
{
//allow more than one member
}
else
{
//allow only one member
```

}

I could try to check **typeof()**, however all item sources are of the same type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so by creating a new Dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowMultipleMembersProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AllowMultipleMembers", typeof(bool), typeof(IP_ListBoxDragDropBehavior_New), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAllowMultipleMembersPropertyChanged)));
```

and in my **OnDrop** event I check for the following:

```
bool? bMoreMembers = this.AssociatedObject.GetValue(AllowMultipleMembersProperty) as bool?;
```